# how to fix firebase function Unhandled error Error

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

i am trying to fetch firebase database in functions but I can't figure out what's causing the error. here's my code

```
exports.test = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
console.log(data)
const sessionID = data.sessionID

const snapshot = await admin.database().ref('/test/'+sessionID).once('v‌​alue');
 console.log(snapshot);
 return snapshot

})
```

this is how I am calling it from client side javascript

```js
function callServer(){

    var signInCartIn = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('signInCartIn');

        var cartInfo = {
            "sessionID":"23234",
            "log":"6425",
            "cuso_id":"cus_IP83EOJ9843s",
            "pjo_id":"tm_1HoKt34xY1b"
        }

        signInCartIn(paymentInfo).then(function(result) {
          // Read result of the Cloud Function.

 
        }).catch(function(error) {
          // Getting the Error details.
          var code = error.code;
          var message = error.message;
          var details = error.details;

          console.log(message)
          // ...
        })

}
```

I keep getting this error when I call the function

> Unhandled error Error: Query.once failed: First argument must be a valid event type = "value", "child_added", "child_removed", "child_changed", or "child_moved".

what is causing the error and how can I fix it?

Comment: You probably want to log and return `snapshot.val()` instead of snapshot (as `snapshot` itself isnot a JSON object). But that shouldn't be causing the error you get. The `once()` call looks fine to me. Are you sure that error is coming from this code?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I thought so too. I have included the client side call to see maybe I'm missing something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What seems to be `value` is not really `value`.

There are hidden characters in there, a `\u200c` and a `\u200b`.

Looks like a nasty copy-paste. Delete it and type it yourself.

```js
const yourValue = 'v‌​alue';
const realValue = 'value';

const yourCharCodes = yourValue.split('').map(c => c.charCodeAt(0)).join(',');
const realCharCodes = realValue.split('').map(c => c.charCodeAt(0)).join(',');
console.log('yourCharCodes:', yourCharCodes);
console.log('realCharCodes:', realCharCodes);
```

Comment: **Great** catch Stratubas. I wish I could upload multiple times. There are indeed two non-visible unicode characters in there (`&#8204;` and `&#8203;`).

Comment: where exactly are they located and were you able to find them?

Comment: @learner101 I don't have a specific method. I just tried copy-pasting your `'value'` in Chrome dev console, to check for `===` with a "normal" `'value'`, and two red dots appeared in the text.